# Channels in networking

Tags: repeater

Quick question about 2.4Ghz and 5.0Ghz freq.I do have a Modem and an AP repeater that both auto choose their channel but for some reason when i restart the modem and it chooses a diffirent channel for wifi, the repeater stops working. And after that when i restart the repeater everything works and all devices run at the channel which the modem last choose.why does the repeater want to be in the same channel as the modem.doesnt that make the channel more crowded thus slower?
The same happens in ac wifi too
Example:in auto mode the modem runs at channel 10 i restart it it runs at channel 11 repeater starts to not work(it says that it cant get an ip adress) i resart the repeater, repeater starts to work in channel 11 as well.why does the repeater not connect automaticly and why are the channels changing?

Comment: Your repeater probably has only a single radio. It must operate the client part on the original AP’s channel. A radio can only be tuned to one channel concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Your (WiFi router/modem) is scanning the spectrum during restart to look for the best available channel to broadcast from. This is an option is available on most routers. You can change it by logging into your router and look for the WiFi options.  Manually choose a channel and see if there is a ~”retain previous ch on reboot”.

Your repeater router looses connected when you reboot and doesn’t know to scan the channels to look see if the channel has changed. I’m not sure if there is an option to reconnect automatically or not. However if you prevent the first router from changing and give it a reboot, the repeated should reconnect just fine.